# Translation from English in Firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

I want a firefox plugin for 5.0. firefox which can translate English word into English( with explaination of the word ) or Chinese by just hover the cursor over the word.

I saw [this](https://superuser.com/questions/182310/firefox-plugin-for-english-learners) question and the answer is not suitable for firefox 5.0. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think [Im Translator](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/imtranslator/?src=cb-dl-featured) is the tool you are looking for.
[Here](http://imtranslator.net/Translator-For-Firefox-ImTranslator_v_3_3_5.asp)is another link for this addon.

Comment: It doesn't do a pop-up translation.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the add-in name [FoxLingo](https://addons.mozilla.org/zh-tw/firefox/addon/foxlingo-translator-dictionary/) and I am okay with it. The translate speed is rather slow, but it support quick translation by selecting the whole word then right click.

I tried 5 or 6 other add-in, and FoxLingo and the best.